# Counting child objects with condition

Tags: automapper

I have a project that has two classes

In Company class I have a child object InsuredCount
I want to fill InsuredCount with a condition, something like this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap().ForMember(covm => covm.InsuredCount, co => co.MapFrom(x => x.Personnel.Count(y => y.InsuredStatus != InsuredStatus.NotCovered)))

public class Company : BusinessUnit
{
public DateTime RegisterDate { get; set; }
public string RegisterPlace { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection Personnel { get; set; }
}
```

This worked!

But when I check it with miniprofiler it executes the query for each Company Personnel

I just want PersonnelCount with condition and I want to exec this with one single query

Please suggest me how i can do that

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the mapping of InsuredCount, and use `AfterMap` to execute the query and set the property.

**Edit (from comments):**

Or, as the mapping you try to perform is on IQueryable, try using the `Project().To<>` from [Queryable Extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions).

`Project().To` has limitations, so if it does not work for you, the next best thing is to materialize the query as you show in your comment and not use AutoMapper. If this is the case (you hit a limitation in `Project().To`), please file bug, so it can be improved.

Comment: but still i have two query,one query for Company and another for personnel,i want just one query

Comment: Are you using EF? if so, that's how it's designed to work if using lazy loading.

Comment: if i write this code like var companydetail = from s in context.Companies
                            select new CompanyViewModel
                            {
                                RegisterDate = s.RegisterDate,
    RegisterPlace = s.RegisterPlace,
    InsuredCount = s.Personnel.count(x=> x.InsuredStatus != InsuredStatus.NotCovered)
                            }; it will woked fine with 1 query

Comment: thanks,i used it and it worked for simple counting,so i guess maybe i can improve it